# How to prevent duplication in view when item is child of an element and also parent of itself

Tags: sql, t-sql, view

Have mapping table consist of data

```
PARENT_SYS_OBJECT_ID    SYS_OBJECT_ID
       18                    38
       38                    38
```

and inside the view I have two condition for the case statement

```
WHEN SE.SYS_OBJECT_ID = 38 AND PSOM.PARENT_SYS_OBJECT_ID = 18 THEN
WHEN SE.SYS_OBJECT_ID = 38 AND PSOM.PARENT_SYS_OBJECT_ID = 38
```

However this will only happen with one case but not the other.
meaning one case will have data, but the other case would have null.

how should I fix this?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Confusing. Can you post the full query?

Comment: Have added more content to the view query

Comment: It appears if you successfully captured both cases.  I would guess that your null comes from the query and since we dont know anything about "NOTES" or "DOCUMENT", we can't help you. Replace the queries with a number or something to ensure your case works as expected.  NOTE: You should tag you question with specific language for better help.

Comment: the problem is that I don't want duplicated entry when the value of PARENT_SYS_OBJECT_TYPE_ID is null, but it seems like there is no way around it.